# How to permenently cache Firebase realtime Database data?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

Say for Example I've an android app like gmail. Older mails are not going to change in anyway, So every time when user opens the app i dont want to download it fomr realtime database instead i can store data to local disk for older mails. How can i permentely store data for some database references in my database  alone so that i can keep listening for new incoming mails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for `keepSynced`, which you can enable on any location in the database. When synchronization is enabled on a location, the client will automatically keep its cache for that data synchronized with the server. It will also prioritize keeping that data in cases where it need to expunge older data from the local cache.

For more on this, see the Firebase documentation on [keeping data fresh](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities#section-prioritizing-the-local-cache).

Comment: I'm little confused with this keepSynced. If a give Reference("OldMesages").keepSynced(true) , all the data inside OldMessages node will be downloaded to Offline, and firebase will never check ONLINE for this reference and  even when i change something in the database manually in that reference nothing inside my app should change? this post tells me something different https://pamartinezandres.com/lessons-learnt-the-hard-way-using-firebase-realtime-database-c609b52b9afb

Comment: There is no way to run Firebase in pure offline only mode for a subset of your data. When you keep a node synced Firebase will also check if the data is updated, but this should be a relatively simple/small check compared to the actual data size.

Comment: But how does firebase check that the data in offline is updated without comparing it with actual online data every time i open app.

Comment: It creates a hierarchy of hash values for subtrees of the local data, then sends that to the server, and compares them to the equivalent hashes there. Then if the hashes are different, the changed substrees are sent back (in your case that would be empty).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Is Firebase by default has keepSynced(true)? If No, Is there any way to check if the particular reference is already in cache or not? I'm asking this because, i wanted to know what are the reference which are already synced and what are not, then i'll just have to put keep synced true for that reference alone?

Comment: Suppose if i add keep synced true for a same reference again and again, will it download the reference again and again? Only 10Mb is cache is allowed for keep synced, Any way to increase it by moving cache to persistance?

Comment: If you don't set `keepSynced` on the node, it may get cleared from the cache before other nodes. Firebase is inherently a cloud-based database that continues to function when you're offline. You seem to have really explicit requirements of how you want your data synchronization to work, in which case Firebase may not be the best solution for you. You might be better off building your own persistence layer, and using some other cloud storage for the data downloads.

Comment: Actually Firebase works pretty well for my application, because a part of my application requires a real time update , only thing is about the history messages. I'm thinking of building a ROOM database for old messages. if I'm not finding messages offline(new device) than i'll goto online and download once, move to ROOM database.